# ¿ VS2008, Como juntar 2 soluciones de proyecto asp.net webforms en una unica solucion?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2008. Tengo una solución con un  proyecto de una pagina web en webforms con unas pantallas de presentación. 
Por otro lado tengo otra solucion con un proyecto de otra pagina web con unos formularios.

¿ Como puedo agregar la segunda solución a la primera para que desde una pagina de la primera solución llame a la ruta del formulario de la segunda solución ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando un servidor IIS para publicar tus proyectos de webforms, se me ocurren estos metodos posibles para resolver tu problema:

**metodo 1)** crea una carpeta en la solucion "principal" que consideres, y vuelca alli todos los archivos de la otra solucion, deberas organizar todo el proyecto que estaba en la 2da solucion para que quede junto a la primera (o sea unir ambos en uno solo)

**metodo 2)** publica ambos sitios separados, cuando queden publicados cada uno tendra su propia url,

**metodo 3)** una alternativa a metodo2 es que el sitio secundario este en un subdominio en iis, con lo que quedara en www.misitio1.com/sitio2 o como sitio2.misitio1.com (depende como lo configures al iis si le indicas subdominio o directorio virtual), con eso te quedan las url como si fuera que es un unico sitio a pesar de ser que tienes 2 proyectos separados.

**nota:**
lo que debes considerar al momento de tocar ese boton que pasa de un sitio a otro (o aun en el mismo sitio de una pagina a otra), es tener un formulario con metodos GET o POST...  ya que es la manera de interactuar de una pagina con otra... sea en el mismo sitio o en distinto...

para ir de un sitio a otro simplemente cuando te rediriges a una pagina del otro sitio es ir a la url de ese sitio,

ejemplo: tienes un sitio www.misitio1.com y www.misitio2.com, por lo que si estas en misitio1.com/mipagina1.aspx y quieres ir a misitio2.com/mipagina2.aspx, deberas hacer un

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.misitio2.com/mipagina2.aspx");
```

con lo que tienes 2 sitios que se pueden comunicar entre si, si necesitas pasar información de una pagina a otra, puedes enviar información mediante un método GET, o sea, enviando datos que se pasan en la misma url, se le denomina querystring a esos parametros y queda una url formada de la siguiente manera:

```
http://www.misitio2.com/mipagina2.aspx?nombre=jose&edad=25
```

para realizar el get o post a otro sitio y poder enviarle datos la manera de hacerlo desde un proyecto webform es el siguiente:

#### GET

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >    
<head runat="server">    
    <title>Página sin título</title>    
</head>   
<body>    
   <form action="http://www.misitio1.com/webform1.aspx" method="get" >    
   Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
   Edad: <input type="text" name="edad" /><br />    
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

esto cuando tocas el boton enviará una petición http que tendra un querystring de la siguiente manera:

```
http://www.misitio1.com/webform1.aspx?nombre=jose&edad=25
```

para recibir dicha peticion luego deberas preguntar por los valores de querystring para ver cada parametro y actuar de acuerdo a ello en el codigo de la pagina que se ha llamado de la siguiente manera:

```
int edad = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["edad"]);
```

#### POST

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >    
<head runat="server">    
    <title>Página sin título</title>    
</head>   
<body>    
   <form action="http://www.misitio1.com/webform1.aspx" method="post" >    
   Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
   Edad: <input type="text" name="edad" /><br />    
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

En este caso la unica diferencia es que se llama con method="POST", lo que permite enviar en vez de por querystring, por parametros en el body del http, para poder recibir dichos parametros, ya no serán parte de la url y deberás procesarlos con metodos similares a este:

```
string nombre = Request.Form["nombre"].ToString();
```

como verás, no es un tema de como organizar los sitios, ya que podrías hacer lo mismo con cualquier sitio en cualquier lenguage y estarías interactuando, esto se puede hacer enviando información a cualquier sitio web de internet, sea enviando una peticion GET o POST, aunque estén en servidores distintos, solo importa indicar la url y que método usar...

*espero que te sea de utilidad mi respuesta, si te sirve por favor aceptala y cualquier duda adicional al respecto, envíame un comentario y trataré de ayudarte.*

Comment: Estupendo ! La idea de los subdominios me servirá !

Answer (score 5):

### Lee esto primero:

Aclaro: a partir de ahora, la palabra *solución* la utilizaré en referencia a la *solución* del MSVC 2008, no como símil de *respuesta*.

Lo primero que te intentaría dar como respuesta es no utilizar MSVC 2008. Si lo estás haciendo, quiere decir que es muy probable que estés en un proyecto heredado. Al mencionar que estás con asp.net webforms, me confirmas que estás efectivamente en un proyecto heredado.

Mi recomendación es que vayas reciclándote de tecnologías y buscando otra empresa, porque lo que te han pedido es la respuesta ÑAPA (una respuesta cutre a una petición aún más cutre) a algo que debían de haber hecho a nivel de arquitectura y no tienen ni ganas ni tiempo en rehacer el proyecto a tecnologías actuales, lo que provocará innumerables dolores de cabeza (y horas extra sin pagar) a mucha gente para que luego te despidan por incompetencia.

Ahora, vayamos a la respuesta.

### Agregar una solución a una solución

Respuesta: no puedes.

La arquitectura de visual studio a la hora de desarrollar se fundamenta en **una** única solución con **múltiples** proyectos dentro de ésta, por lo que no puedes tener una solución dentro de otra.

Eso no quiere decir que no puedas tener en una única solución múltiples proyectos. Pero, de nuevo, hacer esto implica que tu solución se va a volver un titán, un tótem de proyectos que alargará la compilación hasta el infinito, por no haber realizado correctamente una arquitectura o reciclado el proyecto convenientemente.

Esto que te están obligando a hacer es conocido como antipatrón de programación y tiene un nombre específico:

### Conducto de ventilación

Léete este documento para que sepas un poco más acerca de qué te está pasando. Está en inglés, y a partir de ahora, cada vez que mencione *solución*, será como sustituto a *respuesta*, no teniendo nada que ver con MSVC 2008

https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/stovepipe-system

- **Nombre del antipatrón**: Stovepipe System (conducto de ventilación)
- **También conocido como**: Legacy System, Uncle Sam Special, Ad Hoc Integration
- **Escala más frecuente a la que se encuentra este antipatrón**: Escala de sistemas
- **Nombre de la solución refactorizada**: arquitectura de framework
- **Tipo de solución refactorizada**: Software
- **Causas raíz**: Prisa, avaricia, ignorancia, pereza
- **Fuerzas desequilibradas**: gestión de la complejidad, cambio
- **Evidencia anecdótica**: "El proyecto de software está muy por encima del presupuesto; ha cambiado su programación en varias ocasiones; mis usuarios aún no tienen las funciones esperadas; y no puedo modificar el sistema. Todos los componentes son como un conducto de ventilación".

### Trasfondo

El antipatrón conducto de ventilación (stovepipe system o tubería de gas) es un nombre despectivo ampliamente utilizado para software heredado con cualidades indeseables. En este antipatrón, atribuimos la causa de estas cualidades negativas a la estructura interna del sistema.

Una estructura de sistema mejorada permitiría la evolución del sistema heredado para satisfacer las nuevas necesidades de negocios e incorporar nuevas tecnologías sin problemas. Al aplicar la solución recomendada, el sistema podría obtener nuevas capacidades de adaptabilidad que no son características de conductos de ventilación.

[image: Ejemplo de sistema de conducto de ventilación]

### Solución refactorizada

La solución refactorizada para el antipatrón conducto de ventilación es una arquitectura de componentes que proporciona una sustitución flexible de los módulos de software. Los subsistemas se modelan de manera abstracta para que haya muchas menos interfaces expuestas que implementaciones de subsistemas.

[image: Solución refactorizada al conducto de ventilación]

### PD: Gracias

Gracias por indicarnos algo que pasa demasiado en proyectos de software que pasan de ser pequeños a medianos. Es algo que ocurre demasiado, y que cuando ocurre, lo mejor es salir huyendo del barco antes de que se hunda.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación teorica. Te explico que a la 'Solución del proyecto" he agregado un "Proyecto existente" y he abierto un archivo .sln Al hacer esto en el explorador de soluciones tengo la "Solución con su nombre" y de ella cuelgan 2 proyectos ( con 2 rutas una ruta por cada proyecto ). A partir de aquí ¿ como lo hago para que desde un botón en un archivo .aspx del primer proyecto llame a otro archivo .aspx del segundo proyecto ?

Comment: Te lo he dicho: no puedes sin cambiar la arquitectura de ambos proyectos

Comment: Imagino que no te has dado cuenta de lo que estoy intentando decirte, así que seré "breve": tienes que añadir capas a ambos proyectos para que permita la comunicación interprocesos. Cuando digo añadir capas, no me refiero a hacer 2 archivos .aspx que ponga un pipe con un nombre y que se conecte automáticamente con ese nombre que nadie te ha dicho aún. Me refiero a que tienes que realizar una capa a nivel lógico (a nivel físico pueden ser de 5 a 50 archivos adicionales) que te permita que puedas mandar información entre un "programa" (proyecto) y otro. Habla con tu responsable de esto.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu consejo.